# Cakephp datasources setting from user input

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Is it possible in cakephp to setting config/app/datasources take value from user.

For install cakephp we need to change in app.php

```
hostname , username, password , database etc.
```

If I make a php script for input this values from user, is it possible to set this values in app.php file ? Or is it possible set this value dynamically ?

Like as wordpress installation.

Comment: If you don't mind may you provide me an example link ? Or an small example.

Comment: The app [comes with a cli installer](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/src/Console/Installer.php). If you mean via the web, ala wordpress, look at e.g. [how croogo does it](https://github.com/croogo/croogo/blob/master/Install/Controller/InstallController.php). Please recognise that "is it possible to ask the user for some input and for (Cake)PHP to modify files?" has an obvious answer, providing you a specific solution though is off topic (too broad).